# VBA formula inside cell

Tags: vba, excel-formula, formula, xls

I need to put this formula inside a column subset range

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(M3;"#";"");$AG$413:$AK$821;5;FALSE)
```

I wrote this code:

```
XML.Range("V3:V411").Formula = "=VLookup(Substitute(M3, ""#"", """"), $AG$413:$AK$821, 5, False)"".Value = .Value"
```

but doesn't work and I get "Select method of range class failed" error

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, as this is a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the R1C1 format, more stable in macros.

Also, just use the macro recorder.

Don't pass .Value to Excel, it has no idea what that means. What was the plan with that?

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(R[2]C[12],""#"",""""),R413C33:R821C37,5,FALSE)"
```

Or with .Formula:

```
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(M3,""#"",""""),$AG$413:$AK$821,5,FALSE)"
```